# What is the best way to write logs with correlation Id when sending messages as a batch to Azure Service bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

I am currently converting an application that sends messages one by one using Azure Service Bus .net SDK. The current log actually traces the correlation id from individual messages. I am changing the code to deal with a batch of messages and send it to the ASB. Is there any best practice to trace messages when sent as batches? If a message has correlation ID "A", "A" can be traced in the logs all the way. If I send multiple messages, how should I trace them? I am thinking to assign a batch ID which can in turn be used to connect to the individual messages. Are there any best practices for this ?